# Adding JQuery to meteor and writing it without errors

Tags: meteor

I added the JQuery list package to meteor and it recognizes it. But when I write JQuery code inline in `<script></script>` tags in the apps main html file it does not recognize it ( but I don't get an error). When I write JQuery code in my meteor app .js file I get an error. So I am confused as to how one is suppose to write with javascript or added library packages (like JQuery) once they are added. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put general javascript in a container to include it in a specific Meteor template.

For general onLoad scripts that you might be used to, you can encapsulate that code inside a function once the template is rendered
Example:

```
Template.*templatename*.rendered = function()
{
    //do this only on template load
    if(!this._rendered) {this._rendered = true;console.log('Template onLoad');}
    //everything outside if is done every time the template is re-drawn (meteor sends an update)
}
```

Comment: I assume this templating is simply part of handlebars. If I learn Handlebars will all this be second nature ?