# How do I use jQuery UI in meteor?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

What is the correct way to install jQuery UI in a Meteor application? Since it's not a package yet, I added the jquery-ui.min.js and jquery-1.8.3.js that came in the download into the `lib` folder in my meteor project. That is causing the following fatal error:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.
app/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js:9472
})( window );

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at app/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js:9472:5

(.........)

Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: This SO question might fix your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438127/adding-jquery-to-meteor-and-writing-it-without-errors. Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-to-add-other-js-vender-with-meteor

Comment: The second question helped. I moved the files to /public rather than /lib and am not getting a fatal error I haven't experimented actually using the library yet, but the scope of this question was just getting jQuery UI installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have actually added a [jquery-ui meteorite package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/jquery-ui) that you can install

`mrt add jquery-ui`

**Note** this package is version 1.8.16 and is a dependency of the [jquery-ui-bootstrap package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/jquery-ui-bootstrap) which, if installed, will automatically include the `jquery-ui` and `bootstrap-updated` smart packages. (All of which make bootstrap and jquery-ui play nicely together).

To install everything, you can use:
`mrt add jquery-ui-bootstrap`

Comment: isn't it `mrt add ...` instead of `mrt install` ? I'm sure `add` works, `install` didn't work for me

Comment: Dany you're right on. I keep mixing that up. Updated the answer :)

Comment: @TimDog, also in your second example, it's "add" instead of "install" ;)

Comment: I've just done this, and it installed ok, but when I ran the app on my machine (with `meteor`) I got the error:

    Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

    => Errors prevented startup:

    While building the application:
    error: no such package: 'jquery-ui-bootstrap'

Did I miss a step?

Comment: I found my problem - I had installed [meteorite itself](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) without `sudo`'s `-H` flag. Simply typing: `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` solved it.

Answer (score 14):

You need to put jquery UI in the `client` directory otherwise it is loaded by Meteor on both client and server and crash your app.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an alternative jquery-ui package for Meteor that also includes images:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-jqueryui

Use `mrt add jqueryui` (note there's no dash) to install it. I know, this Meteor package proliferation sucks, due to things not getting maintained. But it should all get better soon when Meteor releases its official packaging system.

Answer (score 0):

This question is growing whiskers...  Here is the new and correct way:

> meteor add mizzao:jquery-ui

Comment: Whiskers indeed... I get *error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: jquery 1.11.11, was 3.0.0.*

Answer (score 0):

I made a post on how to do this correctly here

https://dontbeanocoiner.com/blog/dkuhKsg7fac67nnfP

you must install the package jquery-ui-dist  and import as:

```
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui'
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.css'
```

Then copy the images folder to your /public folder.