# Meteor - Why do we need packages for single-file libraries?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I understand that Meteor is all about packages - after all, Meteor is really just a collection of packages.

I understand there are packages created especially for Meteor, like the Iron Router, which would save us a lot of effort recreating a router from scratch!

However, there are packages which I simply do not see the purpose for. For example, I do not understand why there needs to be a [jQuery package](https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-jquery-ui/), as [suggested to be recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049071/2317532) to install jQuery in Meteor. Upon close inspection, it is simply packaging a custom jQuery file. Why can I not simply download jQuery and add it to the `/client/lib/` directory?

This is not the only example - [moder](https://github.com/ckir/modernizr-meteor)[nizr](https://github.com/cwaring/meteor-modernizr), [jQuery Block UI](https://github.com/channikhabra/meteor-block-ui)

**tl;dr**
**Please explain to me *conceptually* the value of using a simple single-file library (e.g. jQuery) inside a package instead of a standalone file**

Comment: Read [this comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/516#issuecomment-12919473) by  [Geoff-Schmidt](https://www.meteor.com/people). he explained clearly why meteor needs its own packaging system.

Comment: I have skimmed the comment, in particular the 'Asset building and bundling' bit. I understand why it needs a packaging system, God yes! But simple assets like the jQuery library can surely be inserted as a simple file (and bundled like any regular .js file)? "the package system needs to integrate nicely with Meteor's asset building/bundling system"

Comment: In few libraries, the authors aren't doing anything specific to  meteor, you can directly include the js and css files. For such libraries, it's all about your preference and how active the meteor package is. I would prefer using a meteor package because you can run `meteor update --packages-only` to update every single packages you have included but some of the packages are inactive for those you have no other option then adding the native js file.

Comment: Yes, you pretty much addressed all my concerns. I see a lot of packages that only have a single file of an out-dated version of the library. I mean, I'd rather check whether the library is outdated myself on a regular basis, than to install a package and rely on the maintainer to keep it updated. But as you said, that's my preference. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the package is maintained, you always have the latest version of the library for free.

If you use two different packages that both make use of the same library, they don't need to include their own copy of the library. Instead they use a package providing the library, and Meteor makes sure only one instance of the library is loaded, and that both packages have access to it.