# What's the reason for having a package for font awesome?

Tags: meteor

I don't understand what the point of having package for fontawsome. I am just add the css file to my client directory. Can someone tell me what is the point of having a package just for a style sheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor - Why do we need packages for single-file libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425117/meteor-why-do-we-need-packages-for-single-file-libraries)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be easy to just include the css file and the fonts in your code.

But with the package

- Its a one-liner to install `meteor add fontawesome:fontawesome`
- Its easy to include in other packages as a dependency
- Its kept up to date
- Its memorable: you can add bootstrap or something off head.
- You could tell someone else how to do it very easily
- Packages allow customisation for Meteor specifics, such as `select2` and diacritics with the spiderable package so others don't have to go through the pain. With font awesome its the path to the font (usually its `../fonts` but it needs to be `/fonts`) to work with nested routes.
- Its very easy to remove if you don't want it.
- The installation is local, so you don't need to be online, as with the method with including the remote css file. (and hence also a lower chance of xsrf)
- Your projects' codebase is a bit smaller.
- Other packages can be added at the same time when you add font awesome e.g `meteor add mizzao:boostrap-3 natestrauser:select2 fontawesome:fontawesome` which can save a chunk of time too.
- Older versions/locking versions are a synch too i.e `meteor add fontawesome:fontawesome@4.2.0`
- Very often you get a meteor specific readme on atmospherejs.com which can be helpful sometimes..
- Packages are precompiled, so each time you change your Meteor app, it can be a bit faster than having the source files since you have to wait for them to be compiled.
- If another package uses `fontawesome:fontawesome`, then you can be sure you won't have two copies of it in your bundled code.
- The css is included in your single minified css file, so instead of the browser requesting two files (in the case of adding it to `<head></head>`, you request one css file for your entire Meteor app, meaning your app is a bit faster to load.

In addition, in general regarding packages

- Packages allow customisation with file loading order
- Packages allow you to add bundled testing/and or restrictions on which platform the package can be used such as Cordova
- Packages can have npm modules embedded that can contain binaries built for a specific architecture (e.g windows, *nix, 32bit or 64 bit all in a single bundle).
- Packages can be attached to Meteor's tool-chain so you can use them during the build process only, or in debug mode only or production mode only.

**Edit: This is about font awesome but I realise there is also a generic, why add a package when I can add it myself that can be applied to any package so I've added a few more reasons that may not specifically apply to font-awesome only.**

Comment: Adding the CSS file to the project is as easy as adding the package. And perhaps I don't want to have an auto-update mechanism, perhaps I want to rely on a specific version, then the package way doesn't fit. Removing one CSS file is also as easy as removing a package and adding a CSS file to the project also serves me local availability, I don't have to be online to work with it. So, most of these reasons are not reasonable (at least to me, at least in case of fontawesome)

Comment: @dasniko I guess its preference. Its like this to make life easier. I guess if we wanted we could also code lots of Meteor bits of code ourselves but the whole idea of the framework is to turn even the slightest bit of boilerplate into one liners. Lots of people would like to just add font awesome, maybe bootstrap 3, perhaps spiderable all in one line. Its also nice to give this way in tutorials because people are less focused with font-awesome & adding in other libraries and more about building their app

Comment: @dasniko I added a couple of other reasons to use packages, also don't forget the path issue when downloading font awesome manually. A path such as `/categories/fiction/harry-potter` would give square icons with library if it's used verbatim with a local install. If you use the remote css way then it won't work offline so its one or the other.

Comment: IMHO for fontawesome it's really not necessary to have a package instead of adding just one css file to the project. I didn't have any problems yet in doing so, not at all! But most (all) of your reasons are ok for 'real' packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you mean with "package". Do you mean you download the font so you can access it locally? If so, then I guess it speeds things up and a less messier code.